# Enumerating the consumers of WMI Events

Tags: windows, wmi

There are many examples in the net which are demonstrating how to subscribe to an event source (like `RegistryValueChangeEvent`), and invoke some code in response to that event.

But is there a way to enumerate such listeners? For example, I'd like to list all scripts or programs (f.e. their PIDs) that are listening to `RegistryValueChangeEvent`. Is this possible in WMI?

Here is an example script file, listening for registry change event, that I'd like to detect:

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIServices=GetObject( _
    "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
    strComputer & "\root\default")

set objSink = WScript.CreateObject( _
    "WbemScripting.SWbemSink","SINK_")

objWMIServices.ExecNotificationQueryAsync objSink, _
    "Select * from RegistryValueChangeEvent Where " & _
    "Hive = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE' and " & _
    "KeyPath = 'SYSTEM\\ControlSet001\\Control' and " & _
    "ValueName = 'CurrentUser'"

WScript.Echo "Listening for Registry " _
    & "Change Events..." & vbCrLf 

While(True) 
    WScript.Sleep 1000 
Wend 

Sub SINK_OnObjectReady(wmiObject, wmiAsyncContext) 
    WScript.Echo "Received Registry Value Change Event" _
    & vbCrLf & wmiObject.GetObjectText_() 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

*This is one of those semi-answers that "gives some additional info" but doesn't solve your question*

If you want to see the **permanent** event consumers, they'll be registered in the WMI `root\subscription` namespace (Win XP & later). Look for instances of the three things that permanent consumers require: __EventFilter, __EventConsumer (or one of the derived types), and __FilterToConsumerBinding.

Unfortunately, that doesn't address how to find **temporary** event consumers - calls to ExecNotificationQueryAsync - which is what you've asked about.
(But I thought I'd mention it in case it's at all helpful.)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. During my search I've seen some tools to view permanent subscription list, coded by Microsoft and hosted on their site. But nothing on temporary subscriptions; I can only suspect this can't be done without exploiting WMI internals (hope I'm wrong).